# Left and right delimiters for a formula split over two lines

Tags: math-mode, equations, delimiters

Consider the following display:

[image]

that can be obtained, for instance, with the following code:

```latex
\begin{align*}
    \{\int_a^b g \; &: \; \text{ a very, very long and painful description of the functions } g\\
                    &\text{ that are used to build this set}\}    
\end{align*}
```

In this display, the set builder is too long to be written on a single line and must be split into two lines. But I can't find a way for the `\left\{` and `\right\}` delimiters to be properly displayed at the correct size (i.e., a size which is adapted to the integral sign in this set, and a size which is identical for both left and right delimiters). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `\biggl\{` in the first line and `\biggr\}` in the second line.

Comment: Worked perfectly! (Feel free to post that as an answer so that I can accept it, if you want.)